# Reflect all changes in every node

Tags: angularjs, rest, api, spring-boot

I implemented a comment reply system using Spring boot, rest api, angularjs technology, everything seems OK and now I have a question but don't know which keyword to search.
What I need is, when there's a new reply (or comments), I need all these changes will reflect on all node that's running my website. I heard about this technology before, now I want to try implementing it.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but one way of doing that would be to use Message Broker pattern. You have a server listening for messages and whenever you post there something, it's pushed to all listeners. Look for Message Broker, Active MQ, Rabbit MQ or Amazon SNS to get the idea.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992442/how-server-sent-event-send-response-to-a-specific-client seems close to my need.